Maximum shiur for chair height for those sitting shivah
According to Halacha, those in aveilut sitting shiva  should sit in shorter chairs, see here. Therefor,  what is the maximum shiur for permitted chair height when defining a short chair when it comes to this Halacha?

It's more like they shouldn't sit in taller chairs. They don't have to sit in chairs at all if they don't want to

@DoubleAA it doesn't seem to be that clear cut that they do not need to sit if they don't want to. Taz 387:1 at the end, writes: מה שכ' שאין צריך האבל לישב ע"ג קרקע אלא כשהמנחמים אצלו פירוש אבל בלאו הכי יכול לעמוד או לילך בחדרו אבל על כל פנים אסור לישב ע"ג ספסל - when people come visit an Avel they must sit, when no one is around they may stand and walk around

@y_g yes but they can sit on the ground not in chairs.

@DoubleAA true say

Going with the understanding that one who is mourning is supposed to sit on the floor, and the general rule that within 3 tefachim is still considered to be connected to the floor:
According to Rabbi Chaim Naeh: one tefach = 8 cm (3.15 in); three tefachim = 24 cm (9.45 in)
According to the Chazon Ish: one tefach = 9.62 cm (3.79 in); three tefachim = 28.86 cm (11.33in)
If it is uncomfortable to sit at 24cm I would imagine most Rabbis would permit one to sit at 28.8cm (or maybe even recommend 28.8 off the bat)

"within 3 tefachim is still considered to be connected to the floor" If the chair isn't physically connected I'm not sure how this helps. The logical corollary seems to be sitting on a very tall chair that's connected to the ground (like many pews) should also be fine since the chair is an extension of the ground.

The numbers in parentheses (9.44 in) and (11.33 in) in this answer are the english equivalents of 3 tefachim

According to https://aish.com/48964551/ Laws of [Shoes and] Chairs:
How low should the chair be? [applicable to Shiva and Tisha b'Av]
According to most opinions it should be less than 12 inches high (30cm). According to some opinions, one may use any chair that is lower than usual, irrespective of its height.
A person who is unable to sit on a low chair may sit on a regular chair. This includes sick or elderly people, and pregnant or nursing mothers.
